# Intellij idea throws error for ReplaceTokens

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am trying to use ReplaceTokens method in one of my gradle project.  The import is like the following
`import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens`. But intellij tells me that tools is not recognised even though my gradle sync is working fine.
Any idea why this is happening? I am using Intellij 2019.1.2

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example?

Comment: Actually the project is a really big one. So need to create a sample project first. By the way I recently migrated to 2019 version, and this problem I am getting in the newer version

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches"?

Comment: Doesn't it work in gradle command line, or only in IDEA?